# Firebase Database Rules: Checking for service account credentials

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

if I have a service account set up and am initializing the app in a firebase function with the service account credentials to do some database maintenance work, how can I restrict the rules in the database so that only the service account is able to access that path in the database, how can I go about it?

The only available options in the auth object appear to be token, uid, and provider.

The only fields available in the service account json file are:
{
"type": "service_account",
"project_id":
"private_key_id":
"private_key":
"client_email":
"client_id":
"auth_uri":
"token_uri"
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url"
"client_x509_cert_url"
}

Answer (score 3):

Service accounts always bypass all security rules.  It's not possible to write any security rules that limit the permissions of a backend SDK initialized with a service account.